# How to simplify the following logic expression?

Tags: logic

I have been trying to simplify

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \bar{a}cb + a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}c\bar{d} $$

where

$$ \bar{a} = \text{not}\ a$$

I assumed I could use XOR somewhere in here, but that did not work. I could pull a few terms out, but I am not sure where that could get me. Maybe something like:

$$\bar{a}(\bar{b}cd + cb) + a(\bar{b}\bar{c} + \bar{b}c\bar{d}) $$

Comment: It's not meaningful to talk about simplification if you don't tell which operations are available or what they cost for you.

Comment: @mathreadler regular simplification of the logical expression using rules of Boolean arithmetic

Comment: So the fewest total number of "and" "or" and "not" operations or what ?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \bar{a}\color{green}{cb} + a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Reorder)$$

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \color{green}{\bar{a}bc} + \color{green}{a\bar{b}\bar{c}} + a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Adjacency )$$

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \color{green}{\bar{a}bcd} + \bar{a}bc\bar{d} +a\bar{b}\bar{c}d + \color{green}{a\bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{d}}+ a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Idempotence)$$

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \bar{a}bcd + \bar{a}bcd + \bar{a}bc\bar{d} +a\bar{b}\bar{c}d+a\bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{d} + a\bar{b}\bar{c}\bar{d}+ a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Adjacency)$$

$$ \bar{a}cd+ \bar{a}bc+a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}\bar{d} $$

In other words, you can combine $\bar{a} \bar{b}cd$ with $\bar{a} bc$ to get $\bar{a}cd +\bar{a} b c$ and you can combine $a \bar{b}c\bar{d}$ with $a \bar{b} \bar{c}$ to get $ a \bar{b} \bar{c}+a\bar{b}\bar{d}$

In fact, some algebras have an explicit rule for this:

$PQ + P\bar{Q}R = PQ + PR$

which is a generalization of Reduction:

$Q + \bar{Q}R = Q + R$

Indeed, you can also do:

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \bar{a}\color{green}{cb} + a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Reorder)$$

$$ \bar{a}\bar{b}cd + \bar{a}bc + a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}c\bar{d} = (Distribution)$$

$$ \bar{a}c(\bar{b}d + b) + a\bar{b}(\bar{c} + c\bar{d}) = (Reduction)$$

$$ \bar{a}c(d + b) + a\bar{b}(\bar{c} + \bar{d}) = (Distribution)$$

$$ \bar{a}cd+ \bar{a}bc+a\bar{b}\bar{c} + a\bar{b}\bar{d} $$

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more advanced than the karnaugh tables you learn in basic textbooks since it uses $\text{xor}$, but if you know how to use them:

$$\begin{array} {c}
 & \text{C D} \\
\text{A B} &
\begin{array} {c|cccc}
          & \text{00} & \text{01} & \text{11} & \text{10} \\ \hline
\text{00} &           &           &     +     &           \\
\text{01} &           &           &     +     &    +      \\ 
\text{11} &           &           &           &           \\
\text{10} &    +      &     +     &           &    +      \\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

Now identify 3 rectangles (side lengths with a power of 2) that identify it:

$$\begin{array} {c}
 & \text{C D} \\
\text{A B} &
\begin{array} {c|cccc}
          & \text{00}                 & \text{01}                & \text{11} & \text{10} \\ \hline
\text{00} &                           &                          & \color{green}{\blacksquare} &  \color{green}{\blacksquare}  \color{blue}{\blacksquare}       \\
\text{01} &                           &                          & \color{green}{\blacksquare} &  \color{green}{\blacksquare}  \\ 
\text{11} &                           &                          &                            &           \\
\text{10} & \color{red}{\blacksquare}  & \color{red}{\blacksquare} &                            &    \color{blue}{\blacksquare}      \\
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

Which lines up in the grid as:

$$\color{red}{\text{Red}} + (\color{green}{\text{Green}} \text{ xor } \color{blue}{\text{Blue}})$$

And since the red tiles are $a\bar b \bar c$, the green tiles are $\bar a c$, and the blue tiles are $\bar b c \bar d$, a simplified formula is:

$$\color{red}{a \bar b \bar c} + (\color{green}{\bar a c} \text{ xor } \color{blue}{\bar b c \bar d})$$

Comment: Alternatively you could use $$a \text{ xor } c \text{ xor } ab\bar c \text{ xor } \bar b c \bar d$$